# Converting two strings to date time format and creating count down timer with these dates in android

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, string-to-datetime

In this question I have two doubts. Firstly I have two string variables named **biddate** and **placeddate** respectively which contains date and time in string format.The **value in biddate is in this format: 17-Feb-14 12:54:00 PM** and the **value in placeddate is also in this format:  15-Feb-14 9:55:38 PM**. I need to convert both the strings biddate and placeddate to the date and time format as given. But I don't know how to do this.

Secondly I need to create a timer in my activity using these two values biddate and placeddate. As it can be seen that biddate value is always higher than product date value, so I need a timer which counts down from biddate to placeddate each second by second.  So the difference between biddate and placeddate should be displayed as: **xx days xx hours xx minutes** remaining, when I start my activity. When the biddate and placeddate difference becomes less than 1 day, the timer should display as **xx hours xx minutes** remaining. When the biddate becomes equal to placeddate, it should display as some message in my activity as bidding ended or somewhat message like that.

I'm a newbie in this android world. So I don't know how to do the above two things. Can any one please help me out by helping me with the program code for the above two things.

Comment: You can use `Joda`(http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for this purpose. The joda documentation should help you to achieve your objective. No one on this site is going to write code for you :). If you have tried something, post your code here, and people will be happy to correct/help you.

Comment: Dude, If I know the answer for my question, then why the hell should I post it here... I mean to say that I'm a new comer to android, and I don't know the functions or anything to do the above scenario. So please understand my situation...

Answer (score -1):

"The value in biddate is in this format: 17-Feb-14 12:54:00 PM and the value in placeddate is also in this format: 15-Feb-14 9:55:38 PM. I need to convert both the strings biddate and placeddate **to the date and time format as given**"

and what is that format?  If you want to format date strings, you should read the documentation for SimpleDateFormat. It is pretty straightforward to format a date string into any format you like. From SimpleDateFormat you can parse your dates into Calendar objects, compare them, then use a Thread or Timer to do the rest.